# Should I port Linux Driver to Mac OS X OR Should I Rewrite it

Tags: linux, macos, kernel, driver, port

I have a **Linux** driver that I would like to use it **Mac OS X**.
I know that the Mac OS X is based on BSD.

Should I try to port my driver to Mac OS X or should I rewrite it in Mac OS X using I/O Kit in C++?

The linux driver is for some PCI device.

Comment: Before anything else: if the Linux driver is GPL and you are not the sole copyright owner, your ported driver must also fall under the GPL.

Comment: @ephemient  Only required if they want to distribute it. Perfectly ok to do whatever you want on your own Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really vague since it really depends on the details of code/hardware/skill(yours) but her is my thoughts on it.

It really depends on the quality of the existing code. If it's not really really bad I would try to port it first and then probably tweak it after I got it running.
But if you think you could do a good/better job (perhaps because you are very familiar with the hardware) in a reasonable time you could write your own.

Comment: I'm afraid that I will spend too much time playing around with the differences between Linux and Mac OS X (Darwin), also I'm afraid that because the driver is Linux Oriented the maintenance will be a mess.

Comment: a little bit, but I don't have any experience with porting to Mac OS that is why I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK (and I'm not an expert), Mac OS X uses its own driver model (called I/O Kit). It's not based on any UNIX-flavored driver model, so you are unlikely to be able to port much of your Linux code.